# Why doesn't `setAllSelected` trigger `listbox.valueChange` events, and how can we make it emit?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, angular-material2

Why isn't `setAllSelected` causing `listbox.valueChange` to emit? How can we ensure it emits?

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { CdkListbox, CdkOption } from '@angular/cdk/listbox';

/** @title Listbox with aria-activedescendant. */
@Component({
  selector: 'cdk-listbox-activedescendant-example',
  exportAs: 'cdkListboxActivedescendantExample',
  templateUrl: 'cdk-listbox-activedescendant-example.html',
  styleUrl: 'cdk-listbox-activedescendant-example.css',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CdkListbox, CdkOption],
})
export class CdkListboxActivedescendantExample {
  @ViewChild('listbox', { static: true, read: CdkListbox })
  private listbox!: CdkListbox<any>;
  ...
  ngOnInit() {
    this.listbox.valueChange.subscribe((result) => {
      console.log({ result });
    });

    this.listbox.setAllSelected(true);

    console.log({ listboxInstance: this.listbox });
  }
}
```

[stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/kkvgmy?file=src%2Fexample%2Fcdk-listbox-activedescendant-example.ts,src%2Fmain.ts)

Answer (score 0):

Under the hook of **cdkOption**:

```
  this.selectionModel.select(...this.options.map(option => option.value));
```

So when you declare **this.listBox.setAllselected(true)** in ngOnit lifecycle-hooks, the value of **options** is still **undefined** and causing **Cannot read properties of undefined**.

When you move it into **ngAfterViewInit**, then the value is correctly defined, after Angular initializes the component's views, etc.

```
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.listbox.setAllSelected(true);
  }
```

You need to wait for the view to be initialized before calling your setAllSelected method.